# Segmentation fault with PyObject_New

Tags: c, data-structures, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, cython

I am trying to write a C extension for python.
This extension is basically just a double linked list.

the following is the peice from the code i have written:-

```
staticforward PyTypeObject linked_list_type;

typedef struct _linked_list_object{
    PyObject_HEAD
    int val;
    struct _linked_list_object *prev;
    struct _linked_list_object *next;
} linked_list_object;

//this method adds a new node to the linked list
static linked_list_object* add_node(linked_list_object * obj, int val)
{
    linked_list_object* new;

    new = PyObject_New(linked_list_object, &linked_list_type);
    if (new){
        new->val = val;
        if (obj)
        {
            new->prev = obj;
            new->next = obj->next;
            obj->next = new;
            new->next->prev = new;
        }
        else{
            new->next = new;
            new->prev = new;
        }
        return new;
        }
        else
        {
        return NULL;
        }
```

After i compile this module and import it into python.

The code throws a segmentation fault.

```
>>> import linked_list
Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped)
```

I noticed that this segmentation fault is not being generated if i comment out

```
new = PyObject_New(linked_list_object, &linked_list_type);
```

and the code below it.

Can someone help me out as to why this segmentation fault is happening.?

I know i am missing something but i cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: This is not a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/), so it's hard to be sure where the problem is. How is `linked_list_type` defined? Are you ever calling `PyType_Ready` on the type object? The provided code never calls `Py_INCREF` on the objects stored in `prev` and `next` nodes, so your reference counting might be wrong. (Since you have a doubly linked list, you would also need to implement [cycle breaker hooks](http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/gcsupport.html?highlight=tp_clear), which are also missing from the code.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this example](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/ext/dnt-basics.html) from the Python docs I think the problem is that you're not providing a fully initialised linked_list_type.

In that example noddy_NoddyType is the equivalent to linked_list_type in your code, and you'll see that at the top they have:

```
staticforward PyTypeObject noddy_NoddyType;
```

like you do.

However further down they have:

```
static PyTypeObject noddy_NoddyType = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,
    "Noddy",
    sizeof(noddy_NoddyObject),
    0,
    noddy_noddy_dealloc, /*tp_dealloc*/
    0,          /*tp_print*/
    0,          /*tp_getattr*/
    0,          /*tp_setattr*/
    0,          /*tp_compare*/
    0,          /*tp_repr*/
    0,          /*tp_as_number*/
    0,          /*tp_as_sequence*/
    0,          /*tp_as_mapping*/
    0,          /*tp_hash */
};
```

As the example explains the member set to sizeof(noddy_NoddyObject) is used by PyObject_New to know how much memory to allocate for the new object.  I believe staticforward is a macro which turns into static, which means that

```
staticforward PyTypeObject linked_list_type;
```

will be created with all fields initialised to zero, so PyObject_New will try to allocate 0 bytes for your new object.  Accessing any of the fields of that object therefore involves accessing memory you don't own and the result is a segmentation fault.